# Django template not rendering correctly on development server

Tags: django, django-templates

When using the development server along with a view and template html file (which both seem to be formatted correctly), Django's server doesn't make the html from the template the source code to the web page like it should, but instead it seems to just render the template as if it were the thing that I wanted to show on the page.  So it seems to create it's own html with my template file being the text that should be printed.  For example, here is the view and template and resulting source code from the web page when run on the development server.

View:

```
def start(request, ampCode):
t = get_template('code_user.html')
c = Context({'user_code': ampCode})
html = t.render(c)
return HttpResponse(html)
```

Template:

```
{% extends "base_code_user.html" %}

{% block title %} This is the title {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<b> {{user_code}} </b>

{% endblock %}
```

Other template that other one extends:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title> {% block title %}  {% endblock %} </title>
</head>

<body>
    {% block body %} {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

Resulting source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1038.35">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Courier}
p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Courier; min-height: 14.0px}
span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1038.35">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Courier}
p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Courier; min-height: 14.0px}
span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p class="p1">&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"&gt;</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>&lt;head&gt;</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>&lt;title&gt;  This is the title  &lt;/title&gt;</p>

<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>&lt;/head&gt;</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>&lt;body&gt;</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span><span class="Apple-tab-span">    </span></p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>&lt;b&gt; AAAAAA &lt;/b&gt;</p>

<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1"></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>&lt;/body&gt;</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">&lt;/html&gt;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe I'm just not understanding what the template system does and it may be working correctly, but I was under the impression that whatever was in the template would become the resulting source code for the page.  Any help on what might be causing this would be helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

When I try your exact example in a django project it works for me (same view names, same template names). Output (assuming ampCode is 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>  This is the title  </title>
</head>

<body>


<b> 3 </b>


</body>

</html>
```

My guess is your problem is somewhere else and not to find in your code samples. Maybe you have problem in your URL conf pointing to a totally different view?

**Previous answer:**

In your view add the`mimetype` to your `HttpResponse`:

```
return HttpResponse(html, mimetype='text/html')
```

If not it will interpret it as `text/plain` by default and therefore not render the html correctly.

If you want to keep things shorter when rendering templates you can simply use the response shortcuts. Have a look at [Django shortcut functions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/).

Comment: Just read over your question again and I might misunderstand it. If this is not the answer your are looking for simply ignore it.

Comment: @Torsten I've tried the mimetype to text/html in the past and I just tried it again now and that still leaves me with the same problem.  Also, I've been using the render_to_response function the whole time but I thought that I'd give the "normal" way a try. Any other suggestions? I haven't been able to figure this out after over a day of searching for an answer.

Comment: It looks to me that your `{% extends "base_code_user.html" %}` doesn't work correctly (the final source code does not include parts from your base template). Are you sure you don't have typo somewhere (in your `code_user.html` or in the name of `base_code_user.html`). Though I am wondering which else template it is using this and why it start the whole html document twice.

Comment: See my edits. When trying your code samples it is working fine for me. Even without the `mimetype`.

Comment: @Torsten It actually seems like the template gets "worked" correctly.  The contents on the screen are what I want the source code to look like.  Interestingly enough, I copied and pasted the contents on the screen into a file and saved it and tried to open it with firefox and I came up with the same source code with all the extra garbage that I don't want. I also tried it with safari and got the same problem there. Do you think it could be some setup problem with my computer?

Comment: I am not sure this has something to do with your computer. Are you running Django in a virtualenv? If not try this one with `--no-site-packages `(it will encapsulate it from your other Python installations and its modules). Maybe you can try to reinstall Django if you don't want to use virtualenv. Except this I really got no clue, mainly because I can not reproduce it.

Comment: @Torsten Just to let you know, I finally figured it out.  I was (stupidly) using TextEdit to deal with the templates and it was storing them as "rich" text instead of plain text. As soon as I told it not to do that it worked perfectly. Thanks again for trying to help. It is always very much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, even I couldn't help directly I am glad it worked out. :)